# Use * in subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:  `finaldata`  and `finalqualification`, and `finlpcqlfctin_qlifictins_id` is the foreign key in `finaldata` i.e. is a primary key in  `finalqualification` table.
I want to get all the data from these two tables through a subquery in MYSQL , but it is showing me an error. My query is:

```
SELECT result.name FROM (SELECT  * FROM  finalpocpassportdata f LEFT JOIN finalpocqualification q ON f.id=q.id)result
```

Comment: which error you get? I think there's a problem on your on clause

Comment: `ON f.id=f.finlpcqlfctin_qlifictins_id` you join on columns from the same table?

Comment: Same column name in both tables?

Comment: Sorry, I did wrong code and I have changed the code now.

Comment: Your modified code doesn't use `finlpcqlfctin_qlifictins_id` mentioned column at all. Is it relevant to the question? And can you finally provide text of error you're getting?

Comment: Error: duplicate column name id

Answer (score 0):

Quick Hint here - if your sub query returns more than one column with the same name it will fall over. We strongly GUID all our data with consistent field names, eg. customerGUID, so I come across this quite regular. Especially when you are using sub queries with joins.

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery return more than value

```
SELECT result.name FROM (SELECT * FROM finaldata f LEFT JOIN finalqualification ON f.id=f.finlpcqlfctin_qlifictins_id)
```

you need to specify the name of column also you have a problem in your alias

```
SELECT result.name FROM (SELECT only_one_column FROM finaldata f LEFT JOIN finalqualification ON f.id=finalqualification .finlpcqlfctin_qlifictins_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT result.name
FROM (SELECT  *
      FROM finalpocpassportdata f LEFT JOIN
           finalpocqualification q
           ON f.id = q.id
     ) result;
```

Obviously, this is a test query, because the subquery is unnecessary and adversely affects performance.

Equally obvious, the `SELECT *` has two columns with the name `id`.  It might have other columns with the same name as well.  But, if `id` are the only duplicates, then one simple solution is to use `USING`:

```
SELECT result.name
FROM (SELECT  *
      FROM finalpocpassportdata f LEFT JOIN
           finalpocqualification q
           USING (id)
     ) result;
```

(Although `NATURAL JOIN` is also an option, I strongly advise not to use it here or anywhere.  It is just bugs waiting to happen.)

If there are other columns with the same name -- which can happen for very reasonable purposes -- then you can list the columns individually.  That is sometimes a pain, it can be easier to use `*` for one table and list from another:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM (SELECT f.*, q.name
      . . .
```

In practice, I cannot see a need for this sort of subquery.  There is little need to do a join as a subquery, because you can have many joins in a single `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so to get name you need subquery

```
SELECT  name FROM  finalpocpassportdata f LEFT JOIN 
finalpocqualification q ON f.id=q.id
```

This query will also give the same result.